# regex check string in camel case without non-character symbols

Tags: php, regex

I got `^[a-z]+([A-Z]?[a-z]+)+` regex to check camel case, how to make it also check that there is no non-character symbols in string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$` at the end of your expression:

```
^[a-z]+([A-Z]?[a-z]+)+$
```